# jQuery: How to hide other accordion content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

How can I hide the content 2 of the 1st header? It should hide all the contents except for the headers.

I tried to use the nextUntil() and nextAll(). I will check again with each().

```
$(function(){
    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil('.head').toggle('slow');
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
```

Thanks.

Sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/pys5T/

Comment: Using your example wht you want to achieve when you click?

Comment: Like an accordion but can open multiple parent divs :) It is working now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using `next()` in function it skip first iteration.

Use it without callng `next()`

Look here http://jsfiddle.net/pys5T/1/

Comment: Thanks @Ashwin it worked perfectly.
I just added this to hide the clild contents from the start:
$('.accordion .content').hide();

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for this:

.next().hide();

If you remove it like so it seems to work.

```
$(function(){

    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
         $(this).nextUntil('.head').toggle('slow');

        return false;
    });

});
```